# Touchable in my flatlist takes a really long time to process when pressed

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

i have a flatlist that shows about 100 profiles. The purpose of the flatlist is to select different profiles for creating a team. However i am having  some performance issues when a profile is selected. When a profile is pressed on the list i update a state variable containing all the ids of the profiles, and i change a vector icon from an unchecked box to a checked box. For some reason it takes quite some time for the touchables onpress function to process.

Here is my component:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import {
  heightPercentageToDP,
  widthPercentageToDP,
} from "react-native-responsive-screen";
import { IProfile } from "../types/cores/profiles";
import { CheckboxComponent } from "../components/cores/checkbox";

interface RenderItemProps {
  item: IProfile;
  handlePress: () => void;
}

export const CreateTeamPage = ({ route }) => {
  const { profiles } = route.params;
  const [teamName, setTeamName] = React.useState<string>();
  const players = profiles.filter((profiles) =>
    profiles.role.includes("ATHLETE")
  );
  const Coaches = profiles.filter((profiles) =>
    profiles.role.includes("ATHLETE")
  );
  const [selectedPlayers, setSelectedPlayers] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
  const handlePress = (id) => {
    setSelectedPlayers((prevSelectedPlayers) => {
      if (prevSelectedPlayers.includes(id)) {
        return prevSelectedPlayers.filter((player) => player !== id);
      } else {
        return [...prevSelectedPlayers, id];
      }
    });
  };

  const RenderPlayerItem = React.memo(
    ({ item, handlePress }: RenderItemProps) => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.rowContainer} onPress={handlePress}>
          <View style={styles.itemRow}>
            <Text>
              {item.lastName.length > 1
                ? item.firstName.charAt(0) + "." + item.lastName
                : item.firstName}
            </Text>
            <CheckboxComponent
              isChecked={selectedPlayers.includes(item.id) ? true : false}
            />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>Create Team</Text>
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.fieldText}>Team name:</Text>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={(text) => setTeamName(text)}
        value={teamName}
        style={styles.textInput}
      />
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <View style={{ width: "50%", height: widthPercentageToDP("50%") }}>
          <Text style={styles.fieldText}>Players:</Text>
          <FlatList
            data={players}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <RenderPlayerItem
                handlePress={() => handlePress(item.id)}
                item={item}
              />
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => {
              return item.id;
            }}
            extraData={selectedPlayers}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

I have tried optimizing my list using React.memo and while that made my lists load a lot faster i still face the issue mentioned in the post.

Comment: Try to use pagination or loadmore concept for huge data. Check this https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration